# How to shorten the code of a svg file without title and desc

Tags: html, xml, svg, title

Here is my svg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg width="26px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 26 25" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <title>942D01BD-6ABD-40A0-BDEA-7F90A7757FFA</title>
    <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
    <g id="Page-1" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill="none" fill-rule="evenodd">
        <g id="Your-orders---empty" transform="translate(-1169.000000, -521.000000)" fill="#E05432">
            <g id="Message" transform="translate(838.000000, 248.000000)">
                <path d="M341.217177,294.432739 C345.070507,292.148372 348.717567,289.648004 351.270153,286.509453 C354.999898,281.923699 354.99812,276.812345 353.451987,271.727827 C353.07679,270.495316 350.505533,271.016989 350.88073,272.250155 C352.385965,277.204418 352.212592,282.00879 348.270353,286.325525 C346.026282,288.782693 343.055822,290.818988 339.927992,292.691645 C340.976233,289.816222 340.880211,286.761453 339.578579,283.813375 C339.049569,282.616864 336.473866,283.12872 337.006433,284.335704 C338.631695,288.017528 338.19515,291.739935 335.795488,295.070268 C335.791931,295.072886 335.787486,295.074849 335.78393,295.077468 C335.433627,295.273832 335.266477,295.534996 335.231803,295.800087 C335.069988,295.997106 334.905506,296.192815 334.729465,296.385906 C333.931949,297.262999 335.448742,298.131582 336.553884,297.729691 C340.873988,296.158124 345.383468,295.608305 350.164121,295.972233 C351.869402,296.101833 351.856954,294.137539 350.164121,294.008593 C347.076301,293.773611 344.104952,293.927429 341.217177,294.432739 Z" id="Fill-1" transform="translate(344.466634, 284.427408) rotate(15.000000) translate(-344.466634, -284.427408) "></path>
            </g>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

So I would like to remove the `title` and the `desc` tag in order to clean the code, but then I have the following error:

> Failed to compile with 1 errors                                 13:43:56
>
> error  in ./src/assets/img/arrow-red.svg
>
> Module build failed (from ./node_modules/file-loader/dist/cjs.js):
>
> Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/user.name/Sites/client/src/assets/img/arrow-red.svg'

My question is the following, can we delete the `title` and the `desc` tag from a SVG ? if no is there a way to clean the code ?
Thanks !

Comment: I don't understand why you can't remove them. I have no problem with it. Try this: `let descs = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("desc"));
descs.forEach(d=>{d.parentNode.removeChild(d)})`

Comment: First of allthank you for your comment, unfortunately I don't understand neither, I am sorry what this code mean ? I am into a really big project using Vue.js so I cannot add random JS like this I guess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the minimum you can reduce all the transforms and groups like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<svg width="26px" height="25px" viewBox="0 0 26 25" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
  <title>942D01BD-6ABD-40A0-BDEA-7F90A7757FFA</title>
  <desc>Created with sketchtool.</desc>
  <path d="M 7.7 20.2 C 12.1 19 16.2 17.5 19.5 15.2 C 24.3 11.7 25.6 6.8 25.5 1.5 C 25.4 0.2 22.8 0 22.8 1.4 C 23 6.5 21.6 11.1 16.7 14.2 C 13.8 16 10.5 17.2 6.9 18.2 C 8.7 15.7 9.4 12.8 8.9 9.6 C 8.7 8.2 6.1 8.1 6.3 9.4 C 6.9 13.4 5.5 16.8 2.3 19.5 C 2.3 19.5 2.3 19.5 2.3 19.5 C 1.9 19.6 1.7 19.8 1.6 20 C 1.4 20.2 1.2 20.3 0.9 20.5 C -0.1 21.1 1.2 22.3 2.4 22.2 C 7 21.9 11.5 22.5 16 24.1 C 17.6 24.6 18.1 22.7 16.5 22.2 C 13.6 21.2 10.7 20.5 7.7 20.2 Z" id="Fill-1" fill="#E05432" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

However, there's no reason that removing those elements should cause a problem, unless theres something special your code does with the title. Run the snippet below...

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="26" height="25" viewBox="0 0 26 25">
  <path d="M 7.7 20.2 C 12.1 19 16.2 17.5 19.5 15.2 C 24.3 11.7 25.6 6.8 25.5 1.5 C 25.4 0.2 22.8 0 22.8 1.4 C 23 6.5 21.6 11.1 16.7 14.2 C 13.8 16 10.5 17.2 6.9 18.2 C 8.7 15.7 9.4 12.8 8.9 9.6 C 8.7 8.2 6.1 8.1 6.3 9.4 C 6.9 13.4 5.5 16.8 2.3 19.5 C 2.3 19.5 2.3 19.5 2.3 19.5 C 1.9 19.6 1.7 19.8 1.6 20 C 1.4 20.2 1.2 20.3 0.9 20.5 C -0.1 21.1 1.2 22.3 2.4 22.2 C 7 21.9 11.5 22.5 16 24.1 C 17.6 24.6 18.1 22.7 16.5 22.2 C 13.6 21.2 10.7 20.5 7.7 20.2 Z" id="Fill-1" fill="#E05432" stroke="none" stroke-width="1" fill-rule="evenodd"/>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you that's really interesting, can you please provide me more details ? To learn how to do it for the future

Comment: @Ced Sure thing, use any svg editor to first ungroup everything (that removes all the `<g/>` tags, then reduce or expand the transforms (the command name varies from application to application). I mostly use [Boxy SVG](https://boxy-svg.com/) for it's simplicity, but sometimes also use Adobe Illustrator.